# Check multiple orders from user

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, shopware

As a frontend I have to write a sql query and I'm struggling with it.

I have a sUsers and sOrders table. I want to delete the users that they didn't order in last 5 years. I wrote a query but it always matches one row from joined table. So when there is only a 1 match user will be deleted. But user can also have newer orders, so I have to check all of the orders that belongs to that user.

Here is my query:

```
$builder = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();

$builder->select('sUser.id as userId, sOrder.id as orderId, sOrder.ordertime as orderTime')
    ->from('s_user', 'sUser')
    ->innerJoin('sUser', 's_order', 'sOrder', 'sUser.id = sOrder.userID')
    ->where('sUser.accountmode = (:accountmode)')
    ->andWhere('orderTime < (:date)')
    ->groupBy('sUser.id')
    ->setParameter(':accountmode', 1, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
    ->setParameter(
        ':date',
        date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-$this->yearsAfterLastOrder years")),
        \PDO::PARAM_STR
    );
```

Is there any other way to check all users orders?